# Debian - Unable to Create Files, Even as Root

Tags: linux, debian

On my Debian server I am running Apache. Today I found that I am unable to create files in all of the website directories. So for example I have /var/www/testsite. I change to that directory.

Then the following command `cp index.php test` results in `cp: cannot create regular file test': Invalid argument'`.

Both the normal and root users are unable to create a file. Other commands souch as 'echo hello > test' fail as well.

However, `mkdir test` succeeds. So I can create directories, but not files.

The directory permissions are 755, same as all the other directories. I can create files in the other directories on the system.

I ran `lsattr .` but am not sure what I was looking at. The result was

`--------------------- ./testsite`

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible that your filesystem somehow got mounted read only? I have seen that too many times on Ubuntu, for sure running on older hardware. (I have seen it sometimes on Debian because it is more stable than Ubuntu 12.04.) "Rebooting and the problem went away" sounds like the first clue in my opinion.

Comment: I had a similar problem, it was fixed by fsck & reboot

Answer (score 0):

This is a longshot, but if you mounted your *htdocs* in *userspace*, for example with *fuse* or *fusermount*, the contents cannot be touched by *root*.

I had similar issues with mounting ecryptfs htdocs into /var/www at logon just because I wanted to encrypt everything externally and mount it for development purposes when required.

Use the user that mounted the directory for editing, make sure that user is in the group used by your webserver, e.g. *www-data*, and have that group with the proper group-permissions set for the mounted files.

Comment: The directories are not separately mounted. They are part of the root filesystem.

Comment: That's weird then, now I am equally curious as you.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't figure it out. I just ended up rebooting and the problem went away.

Comment: Maybe you changed something about users or groups. When you do that, you need to log out and in again until the changes take. Or when it concerns root, you cannot log out so a reboot is required. If you didn't change anything, it will remain one of those mysteries.

Comment: I don't see how a change to users or groups, could cause a cp to fail in a directory, while mkdir works. My best guess is that there was some filesystem corruption, and the reboot ran fsck. However, /var/log/fsck/checkfs did not show anything.